# sencha touch switch views

Tags: view, sencha-touch-2.1

I am using following method to switch between views:

```
Ext.Viewport.remove(Ext.Viewport.getActiveItem(), true);
Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('pulse.view.HomePage'));
```

Is this finest way to do or is there any better way to switch views, because using this code, I am experiencing delay in switching screens.

Is there any way to find out if view is already create by Ext.create or not ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use show() and hide instead of remove() - add(). Ext.getCmp('yourComponentsId').hide();

If it's a dynamic component such as a list, use refresh().
 Ext.getCmp("YOUR_COMPONENTS_ID").refresh();

Comment: This will not display updated contents, could be good for static contents.